# How do I add a line of text to the instructions which are displayed on the node creation form for a custom content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In a node creation form, which is a custom content type, I want to add a text, not a text input field, but just a text line, as a remark or an NB, I search for long time in vain.

How can I do that?

Comment: in Administration » Structure » Content types » Article » Manage fields>>  there is a help section where you can write text which will show when the user is creating the node.  Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: Hello vishal, Thanks for your answer, In fact this help will be displayed in the top of the node creation form. but what I exactly need, is to display a simple texte in different area of the node creation form, I'm using horizontal tabs, so i would like to put in each tab, an explecatif texte .

Comment: pls put a image or something which will show  what you want as its not clear to  me. Maybe then we can solve this

Comment: I'm new here, so I'm prevented to add images :(

Comment: They told me :    Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: go to my profile there u will find my blog. I have two ways to get in touch with me

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the FieldGroup (http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module? If so, when creating a field-group for a content type's fields, select *Vertical Tab* as the type of fieldgroup and once you've placed the fields you want to include 'under' that group, save the page. You will then see a gear icon listed under the Operations menu within the row for your newly created field-group. Clicking on this gear icon will give you some additional options, including a Description area where you can write in instructions or whatever you like that will display on the node creation page within that particular tab and at the top of all the fields you have in that tab.

Comment: Hello Raj,Thank you so much for your answear, this is the solution i've adopted to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add text using the markup form element.

Description: Generate generic markup for display inside forms.

Example from the [documentation:](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup)

$form['contact_information'] = array('#markup' => variable_get('contact_form_information',
t('You can leave us a message using the contact form below.')),
);

Answer (score 0):

This will work to give you overall instructions for the node creation form:

1. Create a new block.
2. Don't give the block a title.
3. Set block body to whatever you want the instructions for the node form to be.
4. Under the "Pages" option of the block creation set "Only the listed pages".  Then add "node/add/[custom-content-type]" for whatever type of content it is.
5. Drag the new block to the top of your content section of your active theme.